# How to set laptop screen brightness just after boot with full disk encryption

Tags: linux-mint, boot, encryption, luks, initramfs

my girlfriend bought `Lenovo Essential G500 i5-3230` and I installed `Linux Mint 16` on it with full disk encryption. It is standard installation with encryption using `dmcrypt` and `LUKS`. But there is a problem with screen brightness, it is set to `0` before it even ask for password to encrypted partitions. I partly fixed it by adding:

```
echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

to `/etc/rc.local` but it fixes brightness after typing correct password to mount encrypted partitions. I want to fix brightness before that, so I can see the password input field. `/etc/rc.local` is loaded after mounting encrypted disk so I think I need to somehow force kernel to change brightness just after it loads itself and before mounting.

Is there a way to tell kernel to adjust brightness just after boot?

Graphic cards on laptop are: AMD® Radeon HD 8570M + Intel HD Graphics 4000

**UPDATE**

I've tried solution sugested by @derobert. I created initramfs script `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/local-backlight-brightness`

```
#!/bin/sh
PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
    prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
    ;;
esac

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
# Begin real processing below this line

echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

And after this:

```
$ sudo chmod a+rx /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/local-backlight-brightness
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
$ sudo reboot
```

But it don't work, screen is almost black when asking for password. I'm not even sure if this script was executed. How can I check if it was executed? Maybe I should add some requirements in `PREREQ=""` to make it work?

**UPDATE 2 FINALLY WORKING**

Ok, I decided to read manual for initramfs-tools again to check if everything was good and it looks like I used wrong boilerplate for my script. The correct one is:

```
#!/bin/sh
PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

. /scripts/functions
# Begin real processing below this line

echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

The problem was with `. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions`. This line was used for hook scripts that are not included in intramfs image. It should be `. /scripts/functions`. After changing it, brightness works like I wanted.

I'm marking @derobert answer as correct because it directed me to correct solution.

Comment: The easy way to make sure it was executed (if you can read the screen at all) is to use `echo` and print out some messages. E.g., put `echo "SETTING SCREEN BRIGHTNESS"` above the other echo line.

Comment: I think it would not be possible because there is playmouth image with linux mint logo. Can I somehow write some message to a boot log file if there is such file?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was graphical... any chance you can turn that off temporarily? Other that, there should be some command to write to the graphical screen. Not sure what it is... all mine are text-mode :-/

Comment: I see that there are some functions for logging: `log_success_msg`, `log_failure_msg` etc. I'm not sure if they will print anything to screen when playmouth image is displayed. I'll try them tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add that script to your initramfs. On Debian (I suspect Mint is the same), it appears that the password prompt comes from `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot`. That script arranges itself to be called last out of the local-top scripts. There is a parallel set of directories in `/etc` intended for local customization. So you just need to plop a file that looks something like:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
     echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
prereqs)
     prereqs
     exit 0
     ;;
esac

echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

into either `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top` or `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount`. The file name doesn't matter, though I'd pick something like `local-backlight-brightness` to make sure it doesn't conflict with some package-provided script. (The prereqs boilerplate comes straight from the initramfs-tools manpage.)

Then, run `update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: What happens when I update my kernel using update manager or synaptic? Will this script be automatically added to initramfs or do I need to run `update-initramfs -u` after each update? I'll try your answer this weekend.

Comment: @piotrekkr It'll be automatically added. Your kernel update actually runs `update-initramfs` behind the scenes (in fact, when you run `update-initramfs` the messages it prints out should look familiar).

Comment: I've tried your solution but it didn't work. See my updated question.

Comment: I was using wrong boilerplate. Your solution is good after using boilerplate from linux mint initramfs manual. Thank you.