# Problem with brightness on OpenSuse 13.1

Tags: linux, opensuse, brightness

I'm using OpenSUSE 13.1 KDE on Lenovo G500 with AMD RADEON and I can't adjust the brightness in any mode I know. I tried to type in a terminal the command `xbacklight -dec percentage` but it doesn't work and it prints the message:

> No outputs have backlight property

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117101/how-to-set-laptop-screen-brightness-just-after-boot-with-full-disk-encryption)...

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have this directory "sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness" 
I tried to create it but can't! Dolhin say : "you can't create this folder" . I used "chmod" command but nothing it changed, so I can't put the script talked in the articles you posted... any ideas?

Comment: I typed in a terminal the command "chmod" as root of course

Comment: You can't create it: the kernel does. Try adding one of the [kernel options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#Kernel_command-line_options) and rebooting.

Comment: There's nothing to do; I've tried a lot of times others options but it still doesn't work

Comment: `No outputs have backlight property` suggest that you are indeed missing the appropriate driver. Either it isn't loaded or there even isn't any available at all - even that is possible (though unlikely). It might be worthwhile to ask on a mailing list as well - see http://lists.opensuse.org/.

Comment: thank you! 
I've forgotten to say that I had actually added by myself xbacklight because it wasn't installed (I don't know Why) during the OpenSUSE's installation! I'll check on the mailing list and then I'll post here the solution!

Comment: at the end I had deleted openSUSE... moderators can close this discussion thanks.